# Getting page not found while simple spring mvc application

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

Hi trying to develop simple spring mvc application using spring 2.6 version.

This is my web.xml file content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springtutorial</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springtutorial</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

This is my application servlet config file "springtutorial-servlet.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="helloController" class="com.net.technicalkeeda.controller.HelloController" />

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="hello.htm">helloController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Jars under lib folder

```
j2ee.jar
jstl.jar
spring.jar
spring-webmvc.jar
```

This is my controller file

package com.net.technicalkeeda.controller;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class HelloController implements Controller {

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("I am here");

        return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp");
    }

}
```

After project deployment in tomcat not able to access through URL

http://domainname.com/springtutorial/hello.htm

Can you please suggest me what is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you missed out to add one of the ViewResolver. There are many ViewResolver available, Here is one of them which you can use.

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

And Just specify

```
return new ModelAndView("hello")
```

or

```
ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
mav.setViewName("hello");
return mav
```